How can I generate a Posgres SQL INSERT statement into a table for each identity in a Python list?
I have a python list of identities (just numbers) and I am trying to create an INSERT statement for postgres SQL for each of the identities, and insert them into a table.
I have tried:
values = [(id, 2940, ts, False) for id in identities_to_deactivate]

sql = "INSERT INTO sval (id, column2, column3, column4) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)"
cursor.executemany(sql, values)
conn.commit()

Where identities_to_deactivate is the python list of identities.
But when I run the above, it throws an error:
-> cur.executemany(sql, values)
(Pdb) n
psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: syntax error at or near ","
LINE 1: ...NTO sval (id, column2, column3, column4) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)

Any ideas how I can fix this?

First, construct a valid SQL Insert statement for postgres SQL like INSERT INTO tablename1 SELECT * FROM tablename2 WHERE id in (864915673, 864915672,...

Whcih connection package are you using?

Okay, apologies I've added the answer below to my question. But I still hit a syntax error, I think it's because I am using PostrgreSQL

Connection package?

Ahh I think it is a special connection package - constructed internally

Instead of using tuple in where clause, you can use list comprehension and build the list first, like so
identities_to_deactivate = [864915673, 864915672, 123456789]
values = [(id, 2940, '2021-12-01', False) for id in identities_to_deactivate]

Values would look like this
[(864915673, 2940, '2021-12-01', False), (864915672, 2940, '2021-12-01', False), (123456789, 2940, '2021-12-01', False)]

Build the insert statement , I have tested in sqllite in local
sql = "INSERT INTO sval (id, column2, column3, column4) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)"
cursor.executemany(sql, values)
conn.commit()

EDIT : POSTGRES, syntax should be fairly same, I am unable to test it as  I dont have postgres in local
conn = psycopg2.connect(
    dbname="your_database", 
    user="your_username", 
    password="your_password", 
    host="localhost", 
    port="5432"
)
cursor = conn.cursor()    
identities_to_deactivate = [864915673, 864915672, 123456789]

sql = "INSERT INTO sval (id, column2, column3, column4) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)"

for identity in identities_to_deactivate:
    values = (identity, 2940, '2021-12-01', False)
    cursor.execute(sql, values)

conn.commit()


Is it possible to use execute instead? I am also trying to pass a bind into the execute statement, so something like: session.execute(sql, bind=session.get_bind(meta_mapper)).fetchall(). I tried it with executemany but it only takes 2 arguments

Actually never mind, let's stick with the original, I am using postgrsSQL and still get a syntax error (Pdb) n psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: syntax error at or near "," LINE 1: ...NTO sval (id, column2, column3, column4) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)

I have added a section for postgres in EDIT, used execute as well as you mentioned,do let me know how you find it @killerbee88

Thanks you so much @samhita it works!
One question though, more of an optimisation question. If my list of identities_to_deactivate was very long, say a few thousand items. Is the above an efficient way to execute each statement?
